# How to sort this?

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-4.0

I have a datatable populated with a nullable year column of datatype `int`.  In addition, every time the year changes, I have added a blank row.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
table.Columns["Year"].AllowDBNull = true;
```

Example of table contents:

```
2005
2005
DBNull.Value
2006
DBNull.Value
2007
```

On a row by row basis and only being able to look at the current row and the next row, how would I sort this so that the `DBNull.Value` rows still separate the difference in years?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the null entry in the database?

Comment: which version of .net framework u r using?

Comment: Are you sure a DataTbale is the best solution here?  And sort on what?

Comment: How should the sort decide which null row to put between two particular years? Or is Year the only column in the datatable?

Comment: @robert - the database does not allow null

Comment: @Jeffrey - It is not the only column.  Basically, everytime the year changes there needs to be a 'spacer' row between the two rows.

Comment: @subt12: are you adding these NULL-rows manually to your datatable for example to provide an Add-record functionality or as a Placeholder? Edit: You should do this via CSS and from RowDataBound(in case of GridView and ASP.Net).

Comment: @Tim - yes the spacer rows are done in the bll.  I still need to determine which rows.  So I guess I don't follow the CSS part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like this sort of design in general, but here is how you could do it.

Add another column of type double, which will be hidden in the display, and call it "SortYear". For the rows with years in them, put the year in this hidden column. For the null rows put the previous year plus 0.5. Then sort by SortYear, then by whatever column you really want to sort by other than year.

```
Year          SortYear  ServiceDescription (or whatever)
2005          2005.0    Internet Service
2005          2005.0    Upgraded Cap Limits
DBNull.Value  2005.5
2006          2006.0    Internet Service
DBNull.Value  2006.5
2007          2007.0    Internet Service



order by SortYear, ServiceDescription
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @subt13 - Even though I answered the question you asked, I would still like to emphasize that this sort of thing is not the way to do software engineering. These sort of hackery, any-way-that-works solutions lead to big problems down the road. You should really never mix data and display elements at this level.

Comment: I'm open to a solution that does not mix data and display elements...  None have been presented thus far, however.

Comment: The best solution depends on what technology you are working with. @Henk Holterman is right that datatables are not a good idea. (They are considered obsolete now, and even if they weren't they shouldn't be holding display elements, and even if they did, they shouldn't be sorted afterwards (i.e., treated as data).) @Tim Schmelter recommends CSS for display, which could be appropriate for the technologies that he mentions. It just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Fair enough.  I will see what's possible with the control I'm using and attempt a solution from the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You need another column to perform the actual sort on. Use a timestamp or something like that, so you can sort in the order they were inserted, but display the Year column the same as you do now.

Comment: Or even just a decimal, 2005.0, 2005.0, 2005.5, 2006.0, 2006.5,.., 2007.0 (where the significant digits in the decimal indicate a separation between years)